# Build Android with no display?

Tags: android, android-things

Is it possible to build Android for a device without a touchscreen? I have in mind a device with no display at all. This would be similar to Android Things SDK, which is not at all ready yet.

Comment: Android TV, Fire TV, and countless Android-on-an-HDMI-stick devices are available for sale. So, yes, it is possible to create an Android device that does not have a touchscreen.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible with Android Things. [Displays are optional](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html#displays_are_optional).

> Android Things supports graphical user interfaces using the same UI
>   toolkit available to traditional Android applications. In graphical
>   mode, the application window occupies the full real estate of the
>   display. Android Things does not include the system status bar or
>   navigation buttons, giving applications full control over the visual
>   user experience.
>
> However, Android Things does not require a display. On devices where a
>   graphical display is not present, activities are still a primary
>   component of your Android Things app. This is because the framework
>   delivers all input events to the foreground activity, which has focus.
>   Your app cannot receive key events or motion events through any other
>   application component, such as a service.